# Unable to connect to mysql on ec2-instance from outside

Tags: amazon-ec2

Am unable to connect to mysql database on ec2 from my current server ..
using telnet i tried to check if the port is open .. but i get the following error ..
"telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused" ..

i checked the security group as well .. and it has MySQLL (port 3306) added ..
The root device for the instance is EBS ..

any clue where i might be going wrong ??

Abhishek

Answer (score 4):

Check the `/etc/my.cnf` or where your MySQL config is stored. It probably contains something like `bind_address=127.0.0.1` and/or `skip-networking`.

Comment: @hithwen Neither should be in there. Restart and `lsof -i` to see if mysql is bound to a local interface.

Comment: After some test, bind_address should be public DNS/Elastic IP if you're connecting from outside or internal IP if you're connecting from other EC2 instance

Comment: Not really. You want to *remove* `bind_address` and `skip-networking` if they are there. And that does that. Then use a security group to lock down access to your other EC2 instances or remote servers.